# "Specified SQL Server not found" when connecting with pypyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server

I've the following, to connect to SQL server.

```
conn = pypyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};server='sqldev\\dwmaster',Database='risk',TrustedConnection=yes")
cur = conn.cursor()
```

However, when I run the application, it throws the error

> pypyodbc.DatabaseError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][DBNETLIB]Specified SQL server not found.')

I am able to access SQLserver from OSQL and SQLCMD.

Comment: They are not duplicate. They are two different issues that I face. One was fixed but I'm struggling with this one.

Comment: It's true that your questions aren't duplicates, but the titles are so similar that a quick glance makes them look the same. It's usually helpful to mention an error or actual problem in a question title, rather than a very generic comment. I've edited the titles of both your questions, hopefully it will help get a better response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your advice Sam.

Finally, solved the problem by setting up a 32 bit ODBC driver, instead of using connection string.

Answer (score 0):

You're either having problems due to network connectivity or due to the named instance.  The named instance is 'dwmaster' / part of the server key/value.  SQL is on tcp 1433 by default, but a named instance may not be on that port or may be on a dynamic port.  To get the port, the client asks the SQL Browser service on UDP 1434 - "What's the port for the DWMASTER instance?"

Some database providers don't interact with the sql browser to find the port that the instance is listening on, so you have to specify it in your connection string. You'd probably want to set the named instance to use a static IP as well.

To rule out the named instance as being a problem, you can see what port it is operating on in the sql management logs when the server starts up.  Specify the port number in your connection string and that may do the trick.  You'll have to consult your pypy docs to see how to specify port.

If you have no success there, you should test connectivity to the dns name and port.  A firewall may be blocking your communication.  You can use telnet, portqry or other tools depending on your OS.  Ping is not a valid test.  If you can't make a connection, you'll want to talk with server/network support.

Telnet test to sql default port

```
telnet myserver -1433
```

Test sql browser

```
portqry -n server -p udp -e 1434
```

Test sql default

```
portqry -n server -e 1433
```